# SQL trigger after update update next row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Columns:
user_id int(11) PK
module_id   int(11) PK
academy_team_id int(11) PK
academy_id  int(11) PK
sort_number int(11)
is_complete int(11)
score_to_pass   int(11)
is_open int(11)
```

Now i wish to add a trigger so that when you update this table if the value `is_complete` is equal to `1` then update the next row's `is_open` and set it to`1`

I have attempted with the following trigger sql:

```
   begin
 if new.is_complete = 1 then
   set next.is_open = 1;
 end if ;
end
```

Sadly this did not work so im not sure how to do it can anyone push me in the right direction?

**According to pala_ Answer**

im getting the following error when updating my row:

```
    ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'user_has_academy_module' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `system`.`user_has_academy_module` SET `is_complete`='1' WHERE `user_id`='1' and`module_id`='11' and`academy_team_id`='49' and`academy_id`='29'
```

Comment: How do you know what the "next" row is? Is there a column to ORDER BY?

Comment: @MarkLeiber well sort_number is one field you could order by

Comment: In an update trigger, you get `old` and `new` prefixes to refer to the previous values and the new values. There is no concept of the 'next' value

Comment: @MarcRasmussen how does `sort_number` work? is it sequential? ie is there always one that is +1 of the previous one? until you get to the last one?

Comment: @pala_ for each user_id, module_id and academy_team_id there is a sort_number that works +1 untill end yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Your basic trigger body should be something like this:</s>

```
begin
  if new.is_complete = 1 and (select id from <table> where user_id = new.user_id and module_id = new.module_id and academy_team_id = new.academy_team_id sort_number = new.sort_number +1 ) then
    update <table> set is_open = 1
      where user_id = new.user_id
        and academy_team_id = new.academy_team_id
        and module_id = new.module_id
        and sort_number = new.sort_number + 1;
  end if
end
```

It will check to see if there IS another thing to set open (based on same `user_id`, `academy_team_id` and `module_id`, and next sequential `sort_number`), and if there is, set it open.

MySQL cant update the same table the trigger is set on. It will need to be done with a stored procedure instead.

```
delimiter //
create procedure completeandopen(IN param INT)
begin
  declare next_id integer;
  declare _user_id integer;
  declare _module_id integer;
  declare _academy_team_id integer;
  declare _sort_number integer;

  select user_id, 
         module_id, 
         academy_team_id, 
         sort_number 
  into   _user_id, 
         _module_id, 
         _academy_team_id, 
         _sort_number 
  from tester 
  where id = param;

  update tester set is_complete = 1 where id = param;
  select id 
  into   next_id 
  from tester 
  where id = param + 1 
    and user_id = _user_id 
    and module_id = _module_id 
    and academy_team_id = _academy_team_id 
    and sort_number = _sort_number + 1;
  if (next_id is not null) then
    update tester set is_open = 1 where id = next_id;
  end if;
end//
delimiter ;
```

I think this should work - i haven't tested on your table structure, and it does assume a unique primary key on your table. If it doesn't have that - it's easy enough to modify.

To use it, just `call completeandopen(id of the row to be completed)` (after changing the table name from `tester` to your table name)

Comment: Hey pala i tried this and i get a syntax error near end ? :s

Comment: I'll need something more specific (ie the full error). -- are you setting your delimiters, and changing <table> to your table?

Comment: il post my full sql: in my question

Comment: I made it work :) however when running an update on the table i get the following error message:

ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'user_has_academy_module' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `Learningbank`.`user_has_academy_module` SET `is_complete`='1' WHERE `user_id`='1' and`module_id`='11' and`academy_team_id`='49' and`academy_id`='29'

Comment: I must be tired. Of course this doesn't work. MySQL doesn't let you do it. If you desire this behaviour you'll need to do it in a stored procedure instead

Comment: i know this might be alot to ask but can you give an example of how that would work?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen try that one - i haven't tested it on your exact table structure yet.

Comment: Just realised i've assumed you have an auto incremented single column primary key. Do you? If not, one would help, otherwise we need to specify more parameters